# how to install github package link using pip

Tags: python, windows, github, pip, tesseract

i want to install this link using pip on windows, python 3.6

https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-vs2012

output:

```
C:\Users\yolo>pip install git+https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-vs2012.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-vs2012.git
  Cloning https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-vs2012.git to c:\users\yolo\appd
ata\local\temp\pip-o2445u8s-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\yolo\\Ap
pData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-o2445u8s-build\\setup.py'
```

[1](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-vs2012):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository that you point to lacks `setup.py` hence it cannot be installed with `pip`. It's also outdated and superseded by https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract.

See the [compilation instructions for w32](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#windows).

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`, then try to install what you want again.

Related: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/56

Comment: one question, is the project in that repo a Python package?

Comment: I doesn't look like it, it looks more like the original Tesseract with support for VS2013. If you want to use tesserOCR, why don't you `pip install tesserocr` or `pip install pytesseract`?

Comment: pip install tesserocr is not working directly, it gives error for leptonica. that's why i need another way to install it.

Comment: try pytesseract. Otherwise, the best solution you could ever find is not using Windows since lots of packages just don't work there (because I believe you're in windows, right?)